# Is WAF implemented for Salesforce APIs?

Tags: api, integration, security

Our client's cybersecurity team is inquiring if Salesforce implements WAF (web application firewall) for its standard APIs.

We have a salesforce application using Sales, Service and Experience cloud.

External apps and Talend job currently use standard Salesforce APIs to load into or export data from the Salesforce org.
These external apps connect to salesforce via connected apps.
Knowing that all inbound connections to or outbound connections from Salesforce org must use TLS 1.2, this normally secures the APIs.

After contacting Salesforce support, they mentionned Salesforce offers an [eCDN WAF for only commerce cloud](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000391240&type=1).

Is the principle of WAF applicable when accessing Salesforce APIs?

What other security measures are implemented currently related to Salesforce APIs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Salesforce publishes the results of annual [SOC-1](https://compliance.salesforce.com/en/soc-1) and [SOC-2](https://compliance.salesforce.com/en/soc-2) audits. These reports go in to all the details that the team might want. I haven't read all the details, so I'm not sure WAF is present, but their controls are some of the best in the industry.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll check this